# Как генерировать случайные адреса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, кладр

Задался вопросом как можно генерировать случайные адреса РФ по введенному городу либо получать их из готовых баз. Нашел библиотеку `faker`, но там просто можно указать локализацию, но не город.

Comment: КЛАДР смотрели?

Comment: @Kromster да. Нашел даже облако КЛАДРа с документацией https://kladr-api.ru/docs, но не понял как получить, допустим, все адреса города Москва